# How to implement pagination with search in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

My pagination is working, even the search is also working. But the problem that I'm having is when i click on next page link in the pagination links. The search is not working for the next page of the pagination. Also I need to know how I send other parameters through the url, and use them in query of pagination. I need help on this as I am novice in **CakePHP**.

In controller page I have used this code:

```
class StatesController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator');

    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 2,
        'fields' => array('State.id', 'State.state','State.code'),
        'order' => array(
            'State.state' => 'asc'
        )
    );

    public function admin_index() {
        $this->layout = false;
        $this->layout = 'adminlayout';

        //****** pagination starts 

        $search=$this->request->data('State.search');

        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        // similar to findAll(), but fetches paged results
        $stateListAr = $this->Paginator->paginate('State',
            array('State.state LIKE' => "%".$search."%")
        );
        $this->set('stateListAr', $stateListAr);

        //****** pagination ends 

        $this->set('stateListAr',$stateListAr);
        $this->render('admin_index');   
    }
}
```

In view page I have used this code:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 'First page')); ?>                  
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say search is not working for next page of pagination. Do you mean that the original search filters are lost?

Comment: Can you provide either a live url to view what you have so far? If that isn't possible, at the very least please post your entire views' source code. Also please specify what extra parameters you are trying to pass through the url.

Comment: Yes  @ChicagoSky , the original search is not working for next page of pagination . Actually that data should be passed or the url should contain that search data . How should i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got solution to my problem , here it is . I have used a code in view page , here  $search variable i have setted data from controller.
    $search);
    $this->Paginator->options(array(
                'url' => $urlParamAr
                ));
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' =>   'disabled'));

```
 echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 'First page'));
```

echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));

```
?>
```